# pycord send discord.ui.View object to specific channel

Tags: discord, pycord

I'm trying to send View object to specific channel.
I've tried this :

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    ch = _bot.get_channel(927913185766436885)
    await ch.purge(limit = 100)
    v = discord.ui.View()
    v.add_item(Vrb())
    await ch.send(view=v)
```

There is `view` in ch.send's hint, But when i put `view=v` to ch.send, It raises:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 352, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "CENSORED", line 2344, in on_ready
    await ch.send(view=v)
  File "C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord_components\dpy_overrides.py", line 350, in send_override
    return await send(channel, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'view'
```

how can i fix this?

#### i don't want to use slash commands or things.

Edit : I'm using version `py-cord-2.0.0a4739+g128a9e97`.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall discord.py or any other discord.py fork if you have any, then install the Development version of Pycord.

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
```